# How to test useEffect with multiple api calls inside using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, jest-enzyme

I want to test useEffect with two api calls as shown below. How can I mock api call or in this case how can I spy on  **fetchCountry** & **fetchStates** functions and then how to test **setCountry** and **setStates** functions

**using Jest & Enzyme**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import fetchCountry from "../fetchCountry";
import fetchState from '../fetchState';
const App = () => {

  const [country, setCountry] = useState();
  const [state, setStates] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData()
  }, []);

 const loadData = async()=>{
  const country = await fetchCountry('Japan');
  const states = await fetchState(country.code)
 
  setCountry(country);
  setStates(states)
 }
```

fetchCountry.js (dummy implementation)

```
const fetchCountry = (countryName) => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    };

    return fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${countryName}`, requestOptions).then(res=>res.ok && res.json());
  };

export default fetchCountry;
```

fetchState.js

```
const fetchState = (countryCode) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  };

  return fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${countryCode}`, requestOptions).then(res=>res.ok && res.json());
};

export default fetchState;
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to test useState hook. It is a part of React and it is already tested by its maintainers.

Let's come back to `fetchCountry` and `fetchState`.

In your test:

```js
const fetchCountryMock = jest.spyOn(fetchCountry, 'default').mockImplementation();

const wrapper = mount(Component);

await flushPromises(); /* You can write your own implementation or use the library
function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}
*/
expect(fetchCountryMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Japan');
```